# Doctype being escaped - how to stop it

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

We have a website admin area where users can edit content for emails.

These emails need to start with `<!doctype html>` - however when the HTML for the email is pasted in - it is escaped - and becomes: `<p>&lt;!doctype html&gt;</p>`

How can I stop TinyMCE altering what users paste in?

(note - only authorised users will be pasting content in so sanitization / security aren't huge concerns).

TinyMCE documentation is opaque at best - I couldn't find anything there or in Google.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a custom button that calls setContent with your HTML content.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow - can you expand on this please?